# How to add reminder,memo in my android calendar given below?

Tags: android, android-calendar

```
public class CalendarView extends Activity  {
    public Calendar month, itemmonth;// calendar instances.
    public CalendarAdapter adapter;// adapter instance
    public Handler handler;// for grabbing some event values for showing the dot
                            // marker.
    public ArrayList<String> items; // container to store calendar items which
                                    // needs showing the event marker
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calendar);
        month = Calendar.getInstance();
        itemmonth = (Calendar) month.clone();
        items = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new CalendarAdapter(this, month);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(calendarUpdater);
        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));
        RelativeLayout previous = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setPreviousMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            }
        });
        RelativeLayout next = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.next);
        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setNextMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            }
        });
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);
                String selectedGridDate = CalendarAdapter.dayString
                        .get(position);
                String[] separatedTime = selectedGridDate.split("-");
                String gridvalueString = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*",
                        "");// taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02.
                int gridvalue = Integer.parseInt(gridvalueString);
                // navigate to next or previous month on clicking offdays.
                if ((gridvalue > 10) && (position < 8)) {
                    setPreviousMonth();
                    refreshCalendar();
                } else if ((gridvalue < 7) && (position > 28)) {
                    setNextMonth();
                    refreshCalendar();
                }
                ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);
                showToast(selectedGridDate);    


            }
        });




    }

    protected void setNextMonth() {
        if (month.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH)) {
            month.set((month.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1),
                    month.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            month.set(Calendar.MONTH, month.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
        }

    }

    protected void setPreviousMonth() {
        if (month.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MONTH)) {
            month.set((month.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1),
                    month.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            month.set(Calendar.MONTH, month.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1);
        }

    }<br/>

    protected void showToast(String string) {<br/>
        Toast.makeText(this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();<br/>

    }<br/>

    public void refreshCalendar() {<br/>
        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);<br/>

        adapter.refreshDays();<br/>
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();<br/>
        handler.post(calendarUpdater); // generate some calendar items<br/>

        title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));
    }



    public Runnable calendarUpdater = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            items.clear();

            // Print dates of the current week
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String itemvalue;
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                itemvalue = df.format(itemmonth.getTime());
                itemmonth.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                items.add("2012-09-12");
                items.add("2012-10-07");
                items.add("2012-10-15");
                items.add("2012-10-20");
                items.add("2012-11-30");
                items.add("2012-11-28");
            }
            adapter.setItems(items);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

//Adapter class
public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private java.util.Calendar month;
    public Calendar pmonth; // calendar instance for previous month
    /**
     * calendar instance for previous month for getting complete view
     */
    public Calendar pmonthmaxset;
    private Calendar selectedDate;
    int firstDay;
    int maxWeeknumber;
    int maxP;
    int calMaxP;
    int lastWeekDay;
    int leftDays;
    int mnthlength;
    String itemvalue, curentDateString;
    DateFormat df;
    private ArrayList<String> items;
    public static List<String> dayString;
    private View previousView;

    // private List<String> mnthString;

    public CalendarAdapter(Context c, Calendar monthCalendar) {
        CalendarAdapter.dayString = new ArrayList<String>();
        month = monthCalendar;
        pmonth = (Calendar) month.clone();
        selectedDate = (Calendar) monthCalendar.clone();
        mContext = c;
        month.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        this.items = new ArrayList<String>();
        df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        curentDateString = df.format(selectedDate.getTime());
        refreshDays();
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
        for (int i = 0; i != items.size(); i++) {
            if (items.get(i).length() == 1) {
                items.set(i, "0" + items.get(i));
            }
        }
        this.items = items;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return dayString.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dayString.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new view for each item referenced by the Adapter<br/>
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        TextView dayView;
        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                    // attributes
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, null);

        }
        dayView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        // separates daystring into parts.
        String[] separatedTime = dayString.get(position).split("-");
        // taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02
        String gridvalue = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*", "");
        // checking whether the day is in current month or not.
        if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) > 1) && (position < firstDay)) {
            // setting offdays to white color.
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            dayView.setClickable(false);
            dayView.setFocusable(false);
            // i++;
        } else if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) < 7) && (position > 28)) {
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            dayView.setClickable(false);
            dayView.setFocusable(false);
            // i++;
        } else {
            // setting curent month's days in blue color.
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

        if (da<br/>yString.get(position).equals(curentDateString)) {
            setSelected(v);
            previousView = v;
        } else {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
        }
        dayView.setText(gridvalue);

        // create date string for comparison
        String date = dayString.get(position);

        if (date.length() == 1) {
            date = "0" + date;
        }
        String monthStr = "" + (month.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
        if (monthStr.length() == 1) {
            monthStr = "0" + monthStr;
        }

        // show icon if date is not empty and it exists in the items array
        ImageView iw = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_icon);
        if (date.length() > 0 && items != null && items.contains(date)) {
            iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            iw.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return v;
    }

    public View setSelected(View view) {
        if (previousView != null) {
            previousView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
        }
        previousView = view;
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_cel_selectl);
        return view;
    }

    public void refreshDays() {
        // clear items
        items.clear();
        dayString.clear();
        // month start day. ie; sun, mon, etc
        firstDay = month.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        // finding number of weeks in current month.
        maxWeeknumber = month.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        // allocating maximum row number for the gridview.
        mnthlength = maxWeeknumber * 7;
        maxP = getMaxP(); // previous month maximum day 31,30....
        calMaxP = maxP - (firstDay - 1);// calendar offday starting 24,25 ...
        /**
         * Calendar instance for getting a complete gridview including the <br/>three<br/>
         * month's (previous,current,next) dates.

        pmonthmaxset = (Calendar) pmonth.clone();
        /**
         * setting the start date as previous month's required date.
         */<br/>
        pmonthmaxset.set(Calendar.DATE, calMaxP + 1);

        /**<br/>
         * filling calendar gridview.<br/>
         */<br/>
        for (int n = 0; n < mnthlength; n++) {
            itemvalue = df.format(pmonthmaxset.getTime());
            pmonthmaxset.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            dayString.add(itemvalue);
        }
    }

    private int getMaxP() {
        int maxP;
        if (month.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MONTH)) {
            pmonth.set((month.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1),
                    month.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            pmonth.set(Calendar.MONTH, month.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1);
        }
        maxP = pmonth.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        Log.i("", "maxP is :         "+maxP);
        Log.e("", "calendar month is :            "+Calendar.MONTH);
        return maxP;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Sanket Kachhela thanks for the edit, Do you have any idea about this?